# How to create redis cluster without replica

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I want to build a redis cluster without replica for testing.

I use cluster create command

```
redis-cli --cluster create AIP:6379 BIP:6379 CIP:6379
```

It always become 1 master and 2 replica, not 3 master.

I also tried addnode and cluster meet , and still get 1 master 2 replicas.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `--cluster-replicas 0`?  [Redis cluster tutorial](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial)

Comment: thanks for response. I have tried create with --cluster-replicas 0 and still get 1master 2replicas

Comment: my final solution: 1.create another redis instance using 6479 port on each vm. 2.create cluster with 3 master and 3 replica.  3.modify cluster to make sure all masters are on 6379 node. 4.remove all 6479 modes and stop 6479 redis instances

Comment: I'm very sure add-node method will change node's role. I have 3 master and 3 replica cluster, and  i want to add another 4 nodes. When i add first node ,cluster have 4 master and 3 replica, but when i add second node it becomes 3 master and 5 replica. One original master becomes other master's replica.